# SignalR different applications on same backplaneDB

Tags: signalr, signalr-backplane

We host different MVC5 web applications for the intranet(500 employees) on server farms. We want to lightly use signalR 2.2 with SQL Server service broker backplane, mainly for server broadcast. We want to use the **same backplane DB for different applications**, all applications having acces to the backplane DB server.

Question : 1-Is it to avoid in terms of performance, I didn't see any good practice guidance and it seems to work technically.  2-If a message is broadcast to application1 clients, will it be sent to clients of Application2 also?3-What would be the advantages of using separate backplane DB for each application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to version 2.x, I don't think that is a good idea because it would probably be inefficient. It might work, but the current mechanism would broadcast all messages to all apps using the same connection string (= same server + same database). There is no way to segregate applications on the same database. It looks like [there is a plan for it in future versions](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2858), but as of today it's probably not recommended.